# Dynamic formula which Sums the Value if criteria is met

Tags: google-sheets

I have been working on sheet where i always apply SUM manual by selecting the each cell separately.

There are multiple sheets where i SUM manually with similar headers that are available in Col"A".

I just want to make SUM formula dynamic.

when it will become dynamic i will drag it from left to right and formula will give SUM result.

I have tried with IF but could not make it and i am sure its not just IF that could make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B5:B, REGEXMATCH($A5:$A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $L2:$L))))
```

[image]